# Looping through a dictionary by every second item

Tags: tcl

I have this structure that I'd like to loop through

`dict  set   gm_info  $gm ....`

The value of `$gm` goes from 0 to 47.

I use this to loop through this dictionary

```
dict for {gm gminfo} $gm_info {       
    dict with gminfo {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to loop by an increment of 2 instead of 1. That is, I want to read gm = 0, 2, 4, 6, ...

Answer (score 2):

It seems easier to do

```
for {set i 0} {$i <= 47} {incr i 2} {
    dict with gm_info $i {
        ...
    }
}
```

This is assuming that the values in `gm_info` are actually dicts.